# SQLAlchemy: How to conditionally choose type for column by depending on its backend

Tags: sqlalchemy, relational-database, portability, sqldatatypes

I want to use [`HSTORE`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.HSTORE) type for a column if it uses PostgreSQL as its backend, or [`PickleType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) otherwise.  The problem is that we cannot determine which backend will be used when schema is being defined (in Python). How can I determine this and conditionally choose the data type when the table actually is created on the backend database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish something like this with [`TypeEngine.with_variant`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant):

```
from sqlalchemy.types import PickleType
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

HybridType = PickleType()

HybridType = HybridType.with_variant(postgresql.HSTORE(), 'postgresql')
```

This creates a new type, `HybridType`, which you can use like any other type, with the caveat that it will produce an `HSTORE` column on Postgres and a `PickleType` everywhere else.